# Android camera API2 unsupported file format

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I'm trying to capture an image via camera2 API, and i'm able to achieve it.

But the main problem is when i try to open that image on mobile phone it shows an error like "unsupported file format". Here's my code so far.

```
SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddhhmmss");
String format = s.format(new Date());
private File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/"+"image_" + format + ".jpg");
protected void takePicture() {
    if(null == cameraDevice) {
        Log.e("tag", "cameraDevice is null");
        return;
    }
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
        Size[] jpegSizes = null;
        if (characteristics != null) {
            jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
        }
        int width = 640;
        int height = 480;
        if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
            width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
            height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
        }
        ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
        List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
        outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
        outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
        final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        // Orientation
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));



        reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);

        final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);

                Toast.makeText(CaptureImage.this, "Saved:" + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                createCameraPreview();
            }

        };

        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                try {
                    session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
            }
        }, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

        Image image = null;
        try {
            image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
            ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            save(bytes);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (image != null) {
                image.close();
            }
        }
    }
    private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        OutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            output.write(bytes);
        } finally {
            if (null != output) {
                output.close();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Any logcat error?

Comment: Its working fine in emulator, but when i try to open it manuallly on my phone "running android 7.0" it says unsupported file format.